# Override files in administrator folder

Tags: overrides

I would like to be able to override files in the ROOT/Administrator/components folder.
How is it possible?

I found this pdf file, but with no basic link to anything:

[link to override plugin pdf](http://wedal.ru/download/JoomlaOverridePluginDocumentation.pdf)

I can't seem to find the right plugin to install. 
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What you are trying to override? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You would add component. Overrides to the admin template.

So for example, if you wanted to override the com_content/views/articles/tmpl/overview.php  component file you would place it in:

/templates/protostar/html/com_content/articles/overview.php

Replacing the protostar with your Joomla! Admin template in view.

If this doesn't answer your post, please be more specific.